mingw g++ を使って ImageMagick++をビルドするとXXX.dllが見つかりませんの原因が知りたい
質問内容
タイトル通りなのですが、mingw g++ を使って ImageMagick++ をビルドすると「XXX.dllが見つかりません」の原因が知りたいです。ImageMagick++ のビルドには成功したのですが、実行ファイルの実行でエラーになります。
.dll等をすべて実行ファイルのディレクトリにコピペしたのですが。質問内容のエラー出ます。これはなぜでしょうか？
環境
OS: Windows 10
Compiler: minGW g++
build: CMake,ninja
知りたいこと
ImageMagick++を使ってビルドしたものを実行すると下記の.dllが必要になるが、公式ファイルを実行ディレクトリに存在してもエラーになる原因が知りたい。
行いたいこと
ウインドウズ版上でMinGW g++を使ってコンパイルしてビルドして実行ファイルを実行したい。
試したこと、調べたこと
1.ウインドウズ版をインストールして、ディレクトリ内の.dllファイルをすべてコピーして実行
2.binフォルダなどをどこかに.dllファイルが存在していないかフォルダを確認しました。
3..batファイル当で自動化してるため念のため、実行ファイルを直接実行
実行エラー




ptreadGC2.dll
libbz2-2.dll
libz-1.dll

参考サイト
取得サイト(Linux Binary Release から ImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gz をダウンロード)：
https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php
初期化コード参考サイト：
https://imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php
CMakeLists.txt (一部抜粋)　ライブラリリンクコード部
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "glfw3")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "opengl32")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "glad")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "imgui")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "freetype")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "libMagick++-6.Q16.dll")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "libMagickCore-6.Q16.dll")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "libMagickWand-6.Q16.dll")


説明文が一部おかしくてはっきりしませんが、見つからないと言われているDLL（libz-1.dll等）はどのフォルダーに置いているのでしょうか？（libz-1.dll等はImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gzには入っていないので別途入手する必要あり）

検索すると、それぞれpthreadGC2.dllはpthreads-w32, libbz2.dllはbzip2, libz.dllはzlibのパッケージに入っているらしいです。ライブラリ名と.dllの間に-1とか-2とかが入っているのは版数管理とからしいですね。詳細は調べてみてください。

CMakeLists.txt は一部抜粋ではなく、すべてを質問に含めてください。同じく、メインのプログラムとなるソースコードや、コンパイル時のコマンド等も分かるようにしてください。

これまでの投稿を見るに、UNIX/Linux環境をメインターゲットにして開発されてきたライブラリ(ImageMagickもその中の一つ)を用いたプログラムをWindowsでコンパイルして使用したいというのが目的のように見えます。それを前提として、包括的な解決策を書きます。
解決策: MSYS2を使用する。
以上です。下記で細かく解説します。

これまでの投稿内容でのパス等から、使用している「minGW g++」とは、おそらく、MinGW-W64-binariesの事だと思われます。まずこれは、MinGWではありません。MinGWの後継としてMinGWからフォークして別の開発者が作ったMingw-w64です。MinGWの後継となるように作られていますが、MinGWの開発者達はMingw-w64の取り入れることや連携を拒否しました。よって、MinGWとMinGW-w64は別のソフトウェアであり、混同してはいけません。細かいことですが、プログラミングではこのような小さな違いが原因で動かないと言うことがよくあります。
なお、MinGWの公式サイトは現在アクセスできない状態で、プロジェクトは完全に停止していると考えられます。MinGWのg++の入手が困難な状態であるため、あなたが本当のMinGWのg++を使ったというのであれば、他の人は同じ環境を作ることが難しいため、解決策が出る可能性は低くなります。本当にMinGWのg++を使用しているという場合でも、Mingw-w64等の別コンパイラーに変更することお勧めします。
ここからはMingw-w64のC/C++コンパイラーを使うという前提で話をします。Mingw-w64のツールチェイン環境(コンパイラーやリンカー、標準ライブラリ等が一式揃った環境)は複数用意されています。Windows以外もありますが、Windos向けで私が一番お勧めするのが、解決策に書いたMSYS2です。
MSYS2はWindows上でUNIX/Linuxライクな環境を提供するソフトウェアです。MSYS2ではpacmanというコマンドを用いて、UNIX/Linux環境で一般的に提供されるソフトウェアやライブラリ及びそのヘッダーをインストールできます。Mingw-w64のコンパイラーはもちろんのこと、ImageMagickも提供されています。ほとんどのヘッダーやライブラリはコンパイラーやリンカーが見に行くディレクトリに置かれる(またはpkg-configで場所がわかる)ため、ライブラリを含むために手動でパスを追加すると言ったことが不要です。インストールし忘れはありますが、パスの設定忘れや間違い、そもそもダウンロードしたモノが違っていた等で動かないと言うことが防ぐことができます。MSYS2上で動作させる限り、DLLがありませんのエラーは極力発生しなくなります。

以上になりますが、MSYS2の細かい使い方は長くなるので、割愛します。自分で調べてください。ちょっとだけ注意点を述べます。

MSYS2では複数の種類のコンパイラー/ターゲット環境が存在します。64ビットのWindows10/11で動作させたいのであれば、ucrt64版がお勧めです。
コンパイルしたEXEファイルはMSYS2上のコンパイル環境で実行して、まずは動くか確認してください。この環境では、必要なライブラリ(DLL)をうまく探してくれるはずです。MSYS2上以外で動作させるには、DLLのコピーが必要です。lddコマンド等でどのDLLを見に行っているかを確認して、そのEXEとDLLを別のフォルダーにコピーし、Windows上から実行してみてください。

